# Sharing research results in platforms that may soon disappear

Tags: publications, open-access

The recent open science/source/access movement has put pressure in publishing not only in open access journals, but also in sharing raw data/figures/etc.

That being said, given the volatility of our current sharing platforms, how can that be done successfully in a way that will last for a significant amount of time and not die out with obsolete technology?

For instance, some people suggest (for instance, [1,2]) sharing and uploading data to ResearchGate, figshare and other platforms, run by companies that are likely to go bankrupt, disappear, be outcompeted or become obsolete in the near future.

If we dig a little deeper, the recent boom in open access journals is also likely to die soon and it is possible that only a few publishers will survive. What happens with the published papers that die with the publishers?

What about the software to read the published data/research notes? How can we guarantee that data will be readable a few years in the future?

Is there a way to publish data/papers that is not subject to the uncertainty of time, making it time-resistance, in some way?

[1] http://science.sciencemag.org/content/354/6308/142
[2] https://gsnmunich.wordpress.com/2016/11/05/how-to-legally-re-use-your-own-figures/

Comment: What is wrong with using version control? I had a quick look at figshare, more specifically at the "Information And Computing Sciences" and "Mathematics" categories, and I didn't see anything which couldn't be stored in a version control repo. Moreover, I find figshare lacking in certain features readily available in most version control solutions, e.g. revision history, branches, wiki, issues, etc.

Comment: So, a related thought.  If a university library gets electronic access to back issues of a journal, can they safely get rid of their paper copies of that journal?  Or if they do that will they regret it in 20 years?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it ask too many questions at once and also looks like a rant in disguise, presenting a lot of unsupported claims.

Answer (score 2):

You could publish the papers and raw-data on the platforms available now, but also store both yourself. Then you could re-upload when platforms change in the future.

Comment: I don't think this solves all issues (and potentially introduces new ones). The purpose of publishing data online is to facilitate its administration. Keeping track of data over decades is already an absurdly difficult task, having to keep track of dying platforms is only going to make it harder.

Moreover, this does not solve the issues of having papers published by journals that may die, or data stored in formats that may be unreadable in the future.

Comment: Saving data like this is not hard, with storage space getting ever cheaper, downloading whole copies of archives is no issue. Keeping everything readable is more challenging with changing formats and standards. Keeping everything (easily) searchable is going to be really hard. However these problems are inherent in any very-long term storage. That is why I advised you to keep an eye on how your publications are stored yourself, because any real solution is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Publishers of subscription journals can participate in backup schemes that archive the journal content and will make it available if the journal publisher goes out of business.  See the CLOCKSS project:

https://www.clockss.org/clockss/News